# I need some tutorials about Tcp in iphone

Tags: iphone, tcp, stock

I want to make a stock software,so i should receive the data from the server.the client have completed,but i don't know how to connect to the server and receive the data.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the Apple sample code. They have plenty of examples of retrieving data from the internet/sockets etc.

Comment: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NetSocket is the basic to start learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a really good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server) on Ray Wenderlich's site about creating a TCP socket based iPhone app. It even shows you how to setup a server.

Comment: thank you ,I have read the tutorial....but it's useless...

Comment: How is it useless exactly? It properly demonstrates how to communicate with a server via TCP sockets which is exactly what you asked for?

Comment: it can't solve my problem,but i have another problem,how to transfer the int ,short to byte array,because i want to write the byte array into outputstream.can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go as deep as TCP/IP when you just want to download new stock information. You should take a look at the NSURLConnection documentation. There are many sample projects listed there, too: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html